# Почему Crypt::encrypt('password') выдает разные значения при каждом запуске?

Tags: php, laravel

Как в Laravel зашифровать/расшифровать пароль?
Делаю вот так, но каждый раз выдает разные значения

```
Crypt::encrypt('password');
```

Comment: Пароли, по-хорошему, не шифруются, а хэшируются. Причём со случайной солью. Поэтому разные результаты при каждом -- совершенно нормально. Это дополнительная мера на случай утекания базы, не дающая перебирать пароли всех пользователей разом по одному алгоритму.

Comment: @D-side не согласен с Вами. В Laravel используется key в файле, благодаря которому происходит двустороннее шифрование (это относительно поставленного вопроса)

Comment: @Legionary я конкретно о паролях. **Шифровать** пароли (обратимым алгоритмом, а не хэшировать, необратимым) это **плохая идея**. Я предполагаю, что ТС это делает для системы аутентификации. Если это так, его лучше дёрнуть за руку сейчас, чем когда его база утечёт и его пользователи пострадают.

Answer (score 1):

Должно работать вот таким образом.

```
$decrypted_secret = Crypter::decrypt(Crypter::encrypt('password'));
```

Более подробно, согласно официальной документации от Laravel:

> Двустороннее шифрование
>
> Двустороннее шифрование позволяет вам извлечь исходные данные из
>   зашифрованной строки — примерно так, как на тех зашифрованных листах
>   бумаги, с которыми вы играли, когда были ребёнком.
>
> В Laravel есть класс `Crypter`, использующий алгоритм AES-256,
>   предоставляемый расширением MCrypt для PHP, поэтому оно требуется для
>   его работы.
>
> Класс `Crypter` имеет два простых метода: `encrypt()` и `decrypt()`.
>   Посмотрим, как с их помощью можно закодировать строку:
>
> `$secret = Crypter::encrypt('I actually like Hello Kitty');` 
> Теперь наш
>   маленький секрет надёжно упрятан под защитой AES-256; в результате мы
>   получили зашифрованную строку — но она нам ни к чему, если бы мы не
>   могли раскодировать её позднее. Посмотрим, как это делается:
>
> `$decrypted_secret = Crypter::decrypt($secret);`
>  Ничего проще! Просто
>   передайте закодированную строку в `decrypt()` и вы получите
>   расшифрованный результат.